# Asking authorization google api without an HTML pop-up

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-drive-api

This is my first question, my team and me are developing a project using the google's API (specifically we are using the realtime APIs under the google drive Apis).

We are trying to authorize the Google Drive Apis without using an HTML pop-up.

We found the [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices) for authorizing an app that will run on devices that do not have access to a system browser.
Unfortunately we discovered that trough this you can't access the drive Api.
(the app will be an app on the computer, but we can't use the browser)
Does anybody knows how can we overcome this problem?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You say "We are trying to authorize the Google Drive Apis without using an HTML pop-up". - so how DO you want the user to authorize your app?

Comment: So we are developing a plugin for a program, and we need to authorize the apis, we are searching a method to not open a pop-up or to open the authorization on a http://www.domain and then fetch the tokens given by google for using the plugin.